# PHP mail.php action opens a new tab when connected to cloudflare

Tags: php, forms, cloudflare

I have a website that I have to move it's nameservers to cloudflare for some optimizations. All went well. Except for this one weird issue, when I press submit on a form it opens a new tab with the URL of `https://my-website/mail.php` instead of sending the the form in the background.

I do not have much experience with PHP, what might be wrong here?

my form's opening tag is as follows:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mail.php" target="hidden_iframe" >
```